# How do I share/mix sound output across the network on Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, audio

I'm looking to replace a hardware mixer with software, to increase the flexibility of our system and reduce hardware complexity

- We have 4-8 server-class PCs (Windows 7) connected in a local LAN via gigabit Ethernet.
- Each PC has a USB sound card which is connected to an 8-input mixer.
- The output from the mixer is sent to speakers in a few places.

What I'd like is change is:

- route the sound over the network instead
- each computer should can thus listen to all others and output it's own "mix"
- less cables
- If possible, support for really cheap hardware (i.e. raspberry pi or something)

There is no hard requirement on latency and such. Up to 100 ms is acceptable (i.e. way higher than your average quake ping...).

While I prefer open source, I'm also open to redistributable commercial solutions, for this to be economically viable, the license costs can't exceed 30-40 €/server. (Preferrably less..)

Grateful for all help!

(Please also share you experiences if possible, not just post links..)

Related question:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297102/how-to-create-a-virtual-sound-card-on-windows <- doesn't seem to interconnect over network